# How to extract timing info from crontab?

Tags: linux, cron

I have a `crontab` entry and would like to extract timing info from it. The goal is to know the frequency of bash script execution which will be executed by `crontab`. This info will be used for further scripting.  In the `crontab -e` entry is :

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /home/test.sh
```

So I want to know whether this script will be executed every 5 mins (or 10mins) using command-line. Can anyone please let me know how to do this?

P.S: frequency of execution of script will vary for different targets and 5mins is just an example here.

Comment: The format in `cron` is pretty clear. What do you expect as output?

Comment: Is /var/log/cron enough useful for you? There you can find exact information about when and what started/executed. So this line gives information about command (bash and script in your case) executed and at what time that happened: `Jan  4 12:49:01 rocky9 CROND[1321]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash /home/test.sh)`. From there you can parse whatever you want, with `awk` for example.

Comment: See `bradymholt.github.io/cron-expression-descriptor/`. Cron versions may vary, and this tool does not understand the interaction between day of week and day of month, and does incomplete validation, but simple cases should be fine. Sample: `7/5 * 23-25 * 3` reports "Every 5 minutes, starting at 7 minutes past the hour, between day 23 and 25 of the month, only on Wednesday".

Comment: To clarify the day of week/day of month issue. In Jan 2023, the day ranges 23-25 .. 3 will execute on the 4th, 11th, 18th, 23rd, 24th, 25th. Only executes once on the 25th, even though that is both the 25th *and* a Wednesday. The simple way to check your time values is to have them run a command like `date '+\%T' >> /home/paul/crontab.log` and `tail -f` the file, although doing that for date args can get boring.